# ReactJS - how to build Routes Dynamically

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

i have created a CMS.

now im trying to create react version of cms's adminPanel and i need to load routes dynamically from an external json file that contains routes information.
admin panel has general features (ex. users, plugins, settings and ...)
and Admin can install new extensions like Blog, Shop and other extensions.
and my question is how to load routes from external json to load components page and class?

eg. created a react admin panel and compiled and user installed blog extension on cms , how to load site.com/admin/blog route to show blog posts and add/delete posts

Comment: In order to get external files you should use Fetch or AJAX to retrieve them... if you use Fetch - you can get a JSON object and then just parse that using [].map.

Comment: @JohnCullen yes thats right. but how to set component attribute in <route /> node?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your project structure... Route requires a Component... on match, that Route will display that Component. The JSON could be something like... `{plugins:[{}, {}], settings: [{}, {}], blogs: [{}, {}]}` then you can loop through the properties of the JSON. I'd render a Route with a corresponding Component and [pass the Component props](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/examples/passing-props-to-children/app.js) based on the JSON property.

Comment: @jihnCullem thanks for answering. I have a cms written in react and compiled (npm run build) i want to add routes to my project from a json that every route's components property are extensions that user installs on cms eg. Blog, shopping ... and routes.json shuld be something like {"routes":[{"path":"/admin/blog", "component":"Blog", "exact":"true"}] ..... and question is after fetching json how i can import Blog component in a compiled app that is pure js not jsx

Comment: @johnCullen read the commnet above.

Comment: @R8_ I need to do something similar, did you ever find out how to do this?